# Mysql Server not start after Migration Assistant in MacOs

Tags: mysql, macos, migration, assistant

I Used Migration Assistant from ios to put my things in another mac.
But, after that, my MySQL Server does not run!

In System Preferences, my computer say:

```
the mysql server instance is not running
```

Whats happing?

I try this:

```
brew services start mysql@5.7
```

And receive:

```
Error: Formula `mysql@5.7` is not installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but my system automatically renamed the MySQL directory during the migration process.

I identified that the **usr/local/mysql/** directory was now called **usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/**

What I did that solved the problem, was to create a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64 mysql
```

I rebooted my mac, and everything worked correctly.

you will probably need to identify the new directory name with the command

```
ls usr/local
```